# Bytecompilation is done with /usr/bin/python and not /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pom.xml, rpmbuild, rpm-maven-plugin

I have a python project and I use maven to create an rpm file, using rpm-maven-plugin v2.1.3.
My project is written using python3.
When I create the rpm file, as part of a larger process of ms creation (with mvn install) I get syntax error on specific python3 syntax.
I can see that bytecompilation is done during the process, using /usr/bin/python which points to python2.7.
How can I force the bytecompile to use /usr/bin/python3?
I cannot change the global env variable since other ms are using python2.7
Also I cannot change the way mvn install is revoked since it's also used for all ms together.
I'm looking for somathing in the project itself I can define or change to force it to use python3.
I don't use a cmake file and I don't write my spec file (it is created as part of the rpm build)

Thank you!

spec file creation:

```
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/BUILD
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/RPMS
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/SOURCES
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/SPECS
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/SRPMS
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/buildroot
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Copying files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/tmp-buildroot/usr/share/yael
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.431Z] [INFO] Creating spec file /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/SPECS/ms-yael.spec
```

Exception Trace:

```
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] Compiling /home/jenkins/workspace/ms_side-pipeline/yael-packer/target/rpm/ms-yael/buildroot/usr/share/yael/yael/yaelFramework/yael1.py ...
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO]   File "/usr/share/yael/yael/yaelFramework/yael1.py", line 33
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO]     def send_response(self, response: Response, metadata: ResponseMetadata) -> None:
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO]                                     ^
[2023-01-03T16:22:00.773Z] [INFO] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

POM plugins:

```
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.3</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <inherited>false</inherited>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>rpm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <group>Networking/Admin</group>
                            <name>myProject</name>
                            <packager>Yael</packager>
                            <prefix>/usr/share</prefix>
                            <version>0</version>
                            <release>0</release>
                            <needarch>x86_64</needarch>
                            <mappings>
                                <mapping>
                                    <directory>myProjectDir/</directory>
                                    <filemode>777</filemode>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>
                                            <location>../yaelDir/</location>
                                        </source>
                                    </sources>
                                </mapping>
                            </mappings>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifacts>
                                        <artifact>
                                            <file>target/rpm/ms-yael/RPMS/x86_64/yaelRPM-0-0.x86_64.rpm</file>
                                            <type>rpm</type>
                                        </artifact>
                                        <artifact>
                                            <file>../git-commit.txt</file>
                                            <classifier>git-commit</classifier>
                                            <type>txt</type>
                                        </artifact>
                                    </artifacts>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

I am trying to build my project using mvn install.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this ... here is what worked for me ... `<defineStatement>__python 3</defineStatement>`

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defineStatements>
                        <defineStatement>__python 3</defineStatement>
                    </defineStatements>
```

Make sure you have `/usr/bin/python3`